# Populate table as data chunks are received

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous, xmlhttprequest

I have a problem with my code and I'm struggling finding why it doesn't work as expected.

I have an API that returns data async. and I want the frontend side to add that data as soon as it's being received. What I expect is an API that returns, say 200 items, then javascript to load those 200 items to a table, meanwhile the API keeps returning another 200 items, and then javascript appends them to the table, and so on until there is no more data left.

I'm using vanilla Javascript 5, prototype-based MVC pattern. Perhaps I'm not getting something simple or its far more complex than I expected.

**resultView.js**

```
//this function gets executed by some other code not relevant
ResultView.prototype.execute = function(serverName, databaseName, query){

    var response = resultController.getData(serverName, databaseName, query);

    console.log("response: ", response); //prints undefined

    response.done(function(data){ // Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'done' of undefined
        console.log("response done: ", response); //doesn't even execute
        data.forEach(populateTable); //this code should populates the table
    });
}
```

**resultController.js**

```
ResultController.prototype.getData = function(serverName, databaseName, query){
    return resultModel.getData(serverName, databaseName, query);
};
```

**resultModel.js**

```
ResultModel.prototype.getData = function (serverName, databaseName, query) {

    var dataSend = {
      //the code that is being sent
    };
    var result = "";
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", url, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
    xhr.onprogress = function () {
        result += xhr.responseText;
        if(xhr.readyState == 4){
            console.log("return: ", result); //shows the results properly each time they are received
            return result; //not sure about this return
        }   
      }
      xhr.send(JSON.stringify(dataSend));
    };  
}
```

I know the data is being received in the API, and the data is returned properly in the front end, the issue must be how I am trying to handle it.

Currently, the results I am getting on the console.log at resultModel.js are the expected, the problem seems to be when calling it from resultView.js, I guess when the function calls `response.done()`, but I am unable to fix it.

Anyone knows how can I approach a solution?
Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

Partially thanks to Ionut, I've managed to make the resultView.js return better datas, but I still have the problem at the resultView.js, when I try to use `response.done(...)` it tells me it can't do `done()` of `undefined`, but the data should be able to be returned. This is my code in resultModel.js now, the rest remains unchanged.

**resultModel.js**

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
console.log("Sending the request...");
xhr.open("POST", urlBase + "QueryResults", true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
    console.log("return: ", xhr.responseText); //data is logged properly
    return xhr.responseText; //it should be returned properly
  }
};
xhr.send(JSON.stringify(queryRequest));
```

Comment: whats the result your're getting?

Comment: I edited my post, I am getting the expected results in resultModel, but no in resultView

Comment: I don't know what `resultController` does, but since you're making an async http request you should have a `callback function` to manage the response

Comment: I'm adding the resultController to clarify

Answer (score 0):

You should add a callback function to manage the full response.
If you want to implement something like lazy-loading you should request your API to send you batches of a smaller number of items, you process them then request more until you get them all.

Here is a basic http request.

```js
console.log('Sending the request ...');
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', "//ipinfo.io/json", true);
xhr.send();

xhr.onreadystatechange = processRequest;

function processRequest(e) {
  console.log('Getting the response ...');
  if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
    var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    console.log('Your ip address is ' + response.ip);
  } else {
    console.log('Error state=' + xhr.readyState + ', status=' + xhr.status);
  }
}
```

Comment: It always tells me the connection is openend, "Error state=1, status=0"